# SQL Creating a "lagging column"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling with trying to create a table in T-SQL. My original table is very simple, it is a table of sales per day, and the date:

```
    Date          Revenue 
-----------      ---------
2018-02-01       151.00 
2018-02-02       200.00
2018-02-03       300.00
```

And so on..

What I would like to do is create a table that has as columns the date, the sales on this date (so just a replica of this table's columns), but now with an additional column with the date with one day subtracted, and the sales on this modified date:

```
 Date             Revenue       Day Before         Revenue on Day Before     
-----------      ---------      -----------      ------------------------
2018-02-01       151.00          2018-01-31            99.00
2018-02-02       200.00          2018-02-01           151.00
2018-02-03       300.00          2018-02-02           200.00
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this table _only_ by date or are there other columns?

Comment: Yes. The table is only by date. The 99.00 was from the row before, which I didn’t write. I haven’t tried anything, because I get confused on how to include the subtracted date in a sub query, if that is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried  `lag()` function ?

```
select Date, Revenue,
       lag(Date) over (order by ?) as  [Day Before],
       lag(Revenue) over (order by ?) as  [Revenue on Day Before]
from table t;
```

Use ordering columns instead of `?` (i.e. `row_id` or `id`)  that could specify your actual data ordering

Comment: Hello. No, I have not seen the lag function before. Could you please elaborate on the order by? statement? Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasMoore.. `?` specify the ordering columns such as some kind of auto-increment columns or you could use `date` column if it is suitable.

Comment: In the example dataset given in the question, the `?` would be `Date`, as that is the name of the column to be ordered by

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select [Date],
       [Revenue],
       DATEADD(day, -1, [Date]) [DayBefore]
       (select [Revenue] from MY_TABLE where [Date] = DATEADD(day, -1, [Date])) [RevenueDayBefore]
from MY_TABLE
```

In solution proposed by @YogeshSharma, if "previous" row, fetched by `LAG`, isn't previous day, than the result would wrong. In my approach you are always sure, that in additional columns, there always be a data from the day before (despite if there's actual data in a table - in this case, it will be `null`). But there's a catch, my solution assumes, that dates within your table are unique.